Using Hierarchical GAMs with interactions
I am trying to use Generalized Additive Models to understand how the seasonal cycles of different zooplankton taxa respond to a climatic anomaly. I want to specify a model in which each taxon (n = 9) has a seasonal cycle that can vary by the climatic variable and time of year. Some of the taxa are not often observed so I would like to use a "global trend" to help with fitting smooths for these less frequently observed taxa. The climatic variable is a year-specific value (measured once per year). Zooplankton are measured from ~20 lakes ~6 times per year. My model is
single.model.zoo <- gam(count ~ group + 
              s(julian_day, climate_anomaly, m = 2) + 
              s(julian_day, climate_anomaly, by = group, bs = "tp", m = 1) +
              s(lake_id, bs = "re") + 
              s(year_f, bs = "re"),
            family = tw(link="log"),
            method = "REML", 
            data = long)

Is this model doing what I think it's doing? I combined a couple of approaches from Pedersen et al. 2019 but I am unsure if this is the correct way to create this model. I would greatly appreciate any help!
